# How to change the content of a variable within an echo statement

Tags: php

I'm a little new to PHP so bear with me. I'm just finishing up this project but I'm having trouble finding a way to output a confirmation message to an empty variable once the submit button is pressed.

I've attempted using various php methods to do this but none seem to work for me, I assume this is to do with some limitation I am not aware of

```
<?php
    $confirmMsg = '';

    echo '<form method="POST"><table>
          <tr><td id="confirmationMsg" colspan="4">Everything look okay?</td></tr>
          <tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Subtotals</th></tr>
          <tr><td class="firstCol">Transistors</td><td>$0.02</td><td>'. $traAmt .'</td><td>$'. TRACOST .'</td></tr>
          <tr><td class="firstCol">Capacitors</td><td>$0.07</td><td>'. $capAmt .'</td><td>$'. CAPCOST .'</td></tr>
          <tr><td class="firstCol">Resistors</td><td>$0.03</td><td>'. $resAmt .'</td><td>$'. RESCOST .'</td></tr>
          <tr><td id="total" colspan="4">Total Items: '. TOTALAMT .'  | Total Cost: $'. TOTALCOST .'</td></tr>
          <tr><td id="confirmTable" colspan="4">'. $confirmMsg .'</td></tr>
          </table>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit Order" id="submitButton"/></form>';

    if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
      $confirmMsg = 'Order confirmed for ' . $cusName . ' on '  . date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
    }
  ?>
```

I want the if statement to check whether the submit button has been pressed and if it has I want it to change `confirmMsg` to the confirmation message listed with the formatting of the echo statement it would be placed into.

Currently I have an empty `tr` and `td` tag to hold the spot and the message should pop up there, but doesn't

Should I just make it so the echo is created upon the button press rather than attempt to alter it? If so, how would that look?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `if` part:

```
<?php
//check if the form was submitted.
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
    $confirmMsg = 'Order confirmed for ' . $cusName . ' on '  . date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
} else {
    $confirmMsg = '';
}

//output the form with message (with content after button submit).
echo '<form method="POST"><table>
      <tr><td id="confirmationMsg" colspan="4">Everything look okay?</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Subtotals</th></tr>
      <tr><td class="firstCol">Transistors</td><td>$0.02</td><td>'. $traAmt .'</td><td>$'. TRACOST .'</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="firstCol">Capacitors</td><td>$0.07</td><td>'. $capAmt .'</td><td>$'. CAPCOST .'</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="firstCol">Resistors</td><td>$0.03</td><td>'. $resAmt .'</td><td>$'. RESCOST .'</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="total" colspan="4">Total Items: '. TOTALAMT .'  | Total Cost: $'. TOTALCOST .'</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="confirmTable" colspan="4">'. $confirmMsg .'</td></tr>
      </table>';

echo '<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit Order" id="submitButton"/></form>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that part out but now when the confirmation message shows up, it deletes the data that was in the other variables(`$traAmt`, `CAPCOST`, `TOTALAMT`, all of them). This probably would go hand in hand with why the `$cusName` isn't appearing in the confirmation message